# Is it possible for turbojet to share parts with turbopropeller or turbocharger?

Tags: post-apocalypse, aircraft, modern

The situation is the following:

- there is slowly rebuilt postapo world
- there is knowledge of "ancient" turbojet engine (including books and possibly even some parts left, though mostly from turbofan)
- there are already operational regional liners using turboprop (think about a rough clone of ATR-72) and there are car engines using turbocharger
- everything is being done on rather tight budgets and small scale, there is literally a single factory with a single production line producing turboprop engine

Would there be a possibility to reuse big chunk of the parts from already existing projects in building a reasonably working turbojet?

Comment: what parts do you want to share? I can assure you, they already "share parts" such as fuel lines, rivits/fasteners and some frame mountings, but these parts do not make a motor one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't push performances too much, you can reuse a good part of the entire airplane.

Just look at the [B-52](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-52_Stratofortress) development history:

at a certain moment it went from being equipped with turboprops (model 464-35)

[image]

to having turbojets (model 464-49)

[image]

The most notable differences are the engines and the swept wings.

If optimization of production and related logistic is a driver for engineering, you can easily force more commonalities and have a modular design as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if **Republic XF-84H Thunderscreech** gives at least a partial answer your question.

It was a turboprop aircraft, and "[t]he turbine engine also provided thrust through its exhaust; an afterburner which could further increase power to 7,230 hp (5,390 kW) was installed but never used".

[source: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_XF-84H_Thunderscreech]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_XF-84H_Thunderscreech)